# Where can I find jar for using WSclient class?

Tags: web-services, grails, jar

Is there any jar required to use WSClient class? If yes, can anyone please tell where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the maven repository to see how to integrate the groovyws lib in diffrent build processes. see: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules/groovyws/0.5.2 or download required jar from http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/groovyws/